# Запуска сайта через Python

Tags: html, python, python-3.5

Как запустить сайт, написанный на *HTML*, через *Python 3.5*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
import http.server
import os

os.chdir("путь_к_каталогу_с_сайтом")
address = ("", 80)
server = http.server.HTTPServer(address, http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: какой будет ссилка? а где указан файл которий я запущу?а если `os.getcwd` видаст ту директорую которая нужна, то `os.chdir("путь_к_каталогу_с_сайтом")` не нужен?

Comment: @lalalala Отвечаю на все вопросы. 1) Любой IP-адрес машины, на которой это запущено или Loopback-адрес (`127.0.0.1`). 2) В адресе, например, `http://127.0.0.1/file.html`. Если ничего не указано, откроется `index.html`. 3) Не нужен.

Comment: это код равнозначен команде: `cd "путь_к_каталогу_с_сайтом"; python3 -mhttp.server 80 --cgi` (если в  ваш код добавить вывод и обработку Ctrl+C).

Answer (score 5):

Просто в директории с html файлами, запустите команду:

```
$ python3 -mhttp.server
```

Эта команда запустит http-сервер, который файлы в текущей директории (`index.html` по умолчанию) позволяет загружать по сети по указанному в выводе команды адресу.

Можно передать порт как аргумент командной строки или задать желаемый сетевой интерфейс через `--bind` параметр. Если нужна поддержка CGI, то передайте `--cgi` опцию.

Comment: Вы действительно думаете, что он сидит на Linux?

Comment: @Sithell http.server работает не только на Linux.

Comment: Это я понял. Просто, судя по орфографии, мне кажется что ТС не догадается, что эту команду нельзя запускать в win cmd в таком виде