# Запуск скриптов из под нативного сервера

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

В каталоге с скриптами запускаю сервер таким образом:

**python -m http.server 8000**

сервер нормально запускается но вместо вывода отображает код скрипта. что нужно сделать чтобы увидеть вывод только функции **print**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В сторону: вместо CGI удобно flask, bottle библиотеки использовать (или дюжины других библиотек).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How to run CGI "hello world" with python http.server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30516414/4279)

Comment: @jfs это для линукс ответ, в виндовс нет корневого каталога /

Comment: корневой каталог не используется в примере. пример работает вне зависимости от системы. (cgi-bin это относительный путь)

Comment: @jfs относительные пути начинаются с символа точки, а не слеша

Comment: не путайте URL и обычные пути.

Comment: @jfs это вы путаете URL и обычный путь а я имел ввиду путь к каталогу к файлам в ОС а не браузере.

Comment: я вам привёл ссылку на вопрос о Windows 7, вы мне говорите: "это линукс ответ" что неверно. cgi-bin вовсе не в корневом каталоге / создаётся. Она задаётся относительно места, где `python3 -mhttp.server ...` команда запущена.

Comment: @jfs если путь в файловой системе ОС начинается с слеша / то это 100% линуксовая (или bsd) корневая точка монтирования. если вы считаете по другому то билл заберет вас ад )

Comment: как я вам уже сказал попробуйте выучить разницу между урлом: /cgi-bin и папкой /cgi-bin. Вы не обязаны сервер в / директории запускать, поэтому если вы передадите серверу /cgi-bin урл, то он вовсе не обязан вам /cgi-bin директорию возвращать—корень сервера и файловой системы это разные вещи (корень сервера это директория где вы команду python3 -m http.server запустили).

Comment: @jfs но / это не относительный путь, это корень web проекта и используется он внутри файлов этого web проекта, а вы моем скрипте где нибудь видели чтоб я где нибудь URL использовал?

Comment: Я напомню вы сказали *"@jfs это для линукс ответ, в виндовс нет корневого каталога /"* в сочетании с вашим последним, комментарием получается что по вашему невозможно на windows "корень web проекта" иметь (что ложно). Повторю в нцатый раз: cgi-bin задаётся относительно директории, в которой `python3 -m http.server...` команда запущена, а вовсе не "корневого каталога". Мне интересно после скольки повторений вы просто попробуете создать cgi-bin папку, положить туда hello.py, запустить сервер с --cgi ключом и убедиться что всё это работает.

Comment: @jfs если сказать утрировано то виндовс это не веб проект. а строка `#!/usr/bin/env python3` из вашей ссылки в скрипте полезет на ФС ОС в каталог /usr/bin/env и будет там искать бинарник python3 .. или вы считаете по другому?

Comment: задайте отдельный вопрос о значении #! строки (shebang) на Windows в контексте Windows pylauncher (py команда) и/или http.server --cgi

Comment: @jfs да не пойду я никуда , балбесу ясно что это указание на того кто должен интерпритровать этот скрипт. в windows есть envoriment variable с именем path вместо этого

Comment: вы заблуждаетесь. shebang и на Windows может иметь значение.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516414/how-to-run-cgi-hello-world-with-python-http-server

Answer (score 2):

Запускаем `python -m http.server --cgi`

Создаем директорию `cgi-bin`

Создаем файл `\cgi-bin\hello.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<h1>Hello world!</h1>")
```

Вот статья в придачу https://pythonworld.ru/web/cgi-1.html

## Проверял в винде и линукс на python 3

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50878/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-erohin------).

Answer (score -2):

Вот так получилось:

имеем скрипты (создаем самостоятельно):

C:\python\srv.py

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

C:\python\cgi-bin\hello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<h1>Hello world!</h1>")
```

выполняем скрипт srv.py

переходим в браузере по ссылке: http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/hello.py

**ВСЁ**

> и учтите просто перейти по ссылке в каталог cgi-bin без указания файла
>   у вас не получится. сервер просто выругается на это.

Comment: Вместо `srv.py`, вы можете [`python3 -m http.server 8000 --cgi` запустить.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602121/23044)

Comment: @jfs я не нашел такого екзешника в каталоге установки, в линукс он может и есть.

Comment: Неужели вам настолько буквальные инструкции нужны, что вы не можете самостоятельно запустить питон 3 на вашей системе. Если python3 команда не запускает Питон 3 у вас, то попробуйте `py -3` команду или проверьте какую версию просто `python -V`  запускает. Такие элементарные адаптации вы должны самостоятельно делать.

Comment: @jfs а кто сказал что я питон запустить не могу?

Comment: я вам привёл команду: `python3 -m http.server ...` Вы ответили: *"я не нашел такого екзешника в каталоге установки, в линукс он может и есть"* Если вы способны  запустить питон, тогда у вас не должно быть никаких проблем адаптировать и запустить: `python3 -m http.server ..` команду под вашу систему.

Comment: @jfs в виндовс нет бинарника python3, есть тот же самый python.exe ) зачем мне python3 писать в консоли не пойму, переименовать его смысла не вижу.. а если вы думаете что при запуске скрипта запускается какая то особая другая версия питона то вы ошибаетесь. Вся замарочка была в том что надо было запускать сервер с CGI поддержкой, а в питоне я не нашел конфига в котором можно указать cgi-bin каталог ну естественно я не знал где он должен находится. Это не линукс у которого пути строго стандартизованы.

Comment: @jfs и! особая благодарность за минус )

Comment: ещё раз: с точностью до **тривиальных** изменений (типа python3 -> python) та же команда работает и на Windows.   Ваш ответ вводит в заблуждение. Нет необходимости создавать srv.py файл.

Comment: @jfs рунет не виноват если вы считаете что на https://pythonworld.ru/web/cgi-1.html статью дурачок написал.

Comment: Я не думаю что для вас это новость, что рунет (и интернет в целом ) может содержать вводящую в заблуждение информацию. https://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @jfs вы тоже часть рунета и если следовать вашей логике вы сейчас вводите меня в заблуждение )))))))))))))))))